# `ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined` when running `react-scripts test --env=jsdom`

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow.js

I'm using a TensorFlow encoder in my application. It works fine in my browser when the application is running but I get issues when testing that it builds:

```
$ npx react-scripts test --env=jsdom
FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined

      16 | import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
      17 | import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
    > 18 | import * as mobilenet from '@tensorflow-models/mobilenet';
         | ^
      19 | import * as UniversalSentenceEncoder from '@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder';
      20 | import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
      21 | import axios from 'axios';

      at new PlatformBrowser (node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/src/platforms/platform_browser.ts:26:28)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/src/platforms/platform_browser.ts:50:30)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/src/index.ts:29:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter/src/executor/graph_model.ts:18:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter/src/index.ts:17:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@tensorflow-models/mobilenet/dist/index.js:38:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/model.js:18:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.js:8:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:3:1)
```

I'd like to get rid of that error. I've tried using the 'text-encoding' package but I'm not sure how get TextEncoder properly defined before the import happens.

Maybe I can set a different option for `--env`?

I get the same error without `--env=jsdom`. I believe I added it after getting similar types of not defined errors and it corrected an issue.

Here is my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

So setting `--env=node` does not work either because: `ReferenceError: document is not defined`.

Comment: The solution, polyfill encoder globally, provided in a similar question solved it for me  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68468204/5404186

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`jsdom` Doesn't seem to have `TextEncoder` defined in global for the DOM. So you can fill it in with the node.js one.

test/custom-test-env.js:

```js
const Environment = require('jest-environment-jsdom');

/**
 * A custom environment to set the TextEncoder that is required by TensorFlow.js.
 */
module.exports = class CustomTestEnvironment extends Environment {
    async setup() {
        await super.setup();
        if (typeof this.global.TextEncoder === 'undefined') {
            const { TextEncoder } = require('util');
            this.global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
        }
    }
}
```

`npx react-scripts test --env=./test/custom-test-env.js`

Comment: Thanks! I made it a little future proof by removing the `require('util')` at the top and using: `if (typeof TextEncoder === 'undefined') {
            const { TextEncoder } = require('util');
            this.global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
        }` in `setup()`.

Comment: Since `typeof TextEncoder === 'undefined'` will always return `false`. Need to change it to: `typeof this.global.TextEncoder === 'undefined'`

Comment: I did this, and add `'testEnvironment': '<rootDir>/test/custom-test-env.js'` on `jest.config.js`

Comment: Nice solution, thank you. If you want to use this env only for 1 file or test you can add those lines to top of your unit test file:

/**
 * @jest-environment ./tests/environments/custom-js-dom-env.ts
 */

Comment: @SerdarD. `'custom-js-dom-env.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module. ts(1208)`. And if I add an empty `export {}` I get: `Unexpected token 'export'` when the test runs.

Comment: Nevermind, solution for me was to use `window.document` instead of JSDom

Comment: Hmm, I tried this as described and got an error "TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null". I had to switch to `jest-environment-jsdom-global`

Answer (score 20):

Thanks for these answers. A simpler format that seems to work, at least with `testEnvironment: 'jsdom'` is:

```
  setupFiles: [`<rootDir>/jest-shim.js`],
```

jest-shim.js:

```
import { ArrayBuffer, TextDecoder, TextEncoder, Uint8Array } from 'util';

global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;
global.ArrayBuffer = ArrayBuffer;
global.Uint8Array = Uint8Array;
```

Comment: This solved the `TextEncoder` error for me (jest 28 w/babel), but, on `import NextAuth from 'next-auth'` I get `TypeError: Uint8Array is not a constructor` :(

Comment: Ok, so if I just REMOVE `global.Uint8Array = Uint8Array;` then the error regarding `Uint8Array` disappears!

Comment: I like this solution because it is dead simple, visually it's very clean

Answer (score 17):

I am getting same error for my Node.Js project. For testing purpose I used jest there. So following steps are resolved my issue

`step-1:` on the root folder of your project add a file named as jest.config.js

`step-2:` Add the following lines in the jest.config.file:

```
    module.exports = {
        testEnvironment: "node"
    };
```

Comment: Thanks.  This worked for me and is the cleaner and shorter solution.

Comment: This deserves 100 up-votes!!!

Comment: For sure if you are using a nodeJS project this should be higher in the documentation

Comment: You could also just leave the default, which is node, and add a docblock at the beginning of your test file

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
test('use jsdom in this test file', () => {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  expect(element).not.toBeNull();
});
```

Ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem when using mongodb. I used [@Phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57713960/4023416) solution with a little change.

First I used `jest-environment-node` instead of `jest-environment-jsdom`:

```js
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');

// A custom environment to set the TextEncoder that is required by mongodb.
module.exports = class CustomTestEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    if (typeof this.global.TextEncoder === 'undefined') {
      const { TextEncoder } = require('util');
      this.global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
    }
  }
}
```

Then I added the environment in the jest configs for all tests as [Cava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3845972/cava) said in the comments:

```js
// package.json
{
  ...
  "jest": {
    ...
    "testEnvironment": "<rootDir>/tests/custom-test-env.js"
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I had to add a decoder as well but this totally worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: [Here is an example](https://github.com/inrupt/solid-client-authn-js/blob/main/tests/environment/customEnvironment.js) of the custom environment configuration file that contains more assignements, and that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

According to the latest [jest v28](https://jestjs.io/docs/28.x/upgrading-to-jest28) and react 18
I had to modify a bit the script

so my preSetup.js

```
const Environment = require('jest-environment-jsdom-global');
/**
 * A custom environment to set the TextEncoder
 */
module.exports = class CustomTestEnvironment extends Environment {
    constructor({ globalConfig, projectConfig }, context) {
        super({ globalConfig, projectConfig }, context);
        if (typeof this.global.TextEncoder === 'undefined') {
            const { TextEncoder } = require('util');
            this.global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to `src/setupTests.ts`

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { TextEncoder } from 'util';

global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the previously posted solutions worked in our case. The only thing that did help was adding the following lines to our **jest.config.js** file:

```js
module.exports = {
      globals: {
        TextEncoder: require('util').TextEncoder,
        TextDecoder: require('util').TextDecoder,
      },
};
```

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

```js
module.exports = {
      globals: {
        TextEncoder: require('util').TextEncoder,
        TextDecoder: require('util').TextDecoder,
      },
};
```

it worked for me! for newbie: remember to add lib:

```
yarn add util
```

Comment: By far the cleanest answer of the bunch

Answer (score 2):

next babel works

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined

      1 | import assert from 'assert'
    > 2 | import { fromUrl, parseDomain, ParseResultType } from 'parse-domain'
        | ^
      3 | import { toUnicode } from 'punycode'
```

```js
// ...
setupFiles: [`<rootDir>/jest-shim.js`],
testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
// ...
```

```js
import { TextDecoder, TextEncoder } from 'util'

global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder
global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt work using below config

```js
"testEnvironment": "<rootDir>/tests/custom-test-env.js"

const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');

// A custom environment to set the TextEncoder that is required by mongodb.
module.exports = class CustomTestEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    if (typeof this.global.TextEncoder === 'undefined') {
      const { TextEncoder } = require('util');
      this.global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
    }
  }
}
```

using "jest": "^28.0.3",

Answer (score 0):

Although all other answers seems to work fine, but I couldn't use any of them in my `react-scripts` app.

to fix the problem, I used [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69588364/2396376) and it solved my issue.

This approach doesn't require adding a test environment as `jest` config.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to wrap `jest-environment-jsdom` module with something that augment the env once and use that file instead in `jest.config.js` ... at least [this solution](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2524#issuecomment-1480930523) worked well for us and it can be extended to include more missing globals.