# Why am I getting "TextEncoder is not defined" in Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jsdom

When testing a function that uses either the [`TextEncoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) or the [`TextDecoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) I get:

```
ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
ReferenceError: TextDecoder is not defined
```

I am using [jsdom](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string), so why is this not working?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

While it should be bundled with jsdom, it isn't with jsdom 16. Therefore you can polyfill like so:

```
import { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } from 'util';

Object.assign(global, { TextDecoder, TextEncoder });
```

You will have to add that to the test or to a [setupFile](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array) like `setup.jest.ts`.

Comment: Where should this be added?  I added it to the file that housing my failing test I get this error under global.TextDecoder Type 'typeof TextDecoder' is not assignable to type '{ new (label?: string | undefined, options?: TextDecoderOptions | undefined): TextDecoder; prototype: TextDecoder; }'

Comment: @dragonfly02 You will have to add that to the test or to a [setupFile](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array)

Comment: In my case, I had to do:
```
import {
  TextDecoder as ImportedTextDecoder,
  TextEncoder as ImportedTextEncoder,
} from "util";

Object.assign(global, {
  TextDecoder: ImportedTextDecoder,
  TextEncoder: ImportedTextEncoder,
});
```

Answer (score 34):

I received this error as well and am using the standard Next.js jest and react testing library test setup outlined in the docs here: https://nextjs.org/docs/testing#setting-up-jest-with-the-rust-compiler.

In particular, it uses the `testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom'`
test environment in `jest.config.js` configuration file.

Unfortunately, importing jsdom in one of my backend api routes (Express routes) broke my tests, giving me the `TextEncoder is not defined` error.

I was able to fix it by adding the following *to the top of the file that housed the broken test*:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */
// my-broken-node-only-test.js
```

> Read more about this technique via [the jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string).

> Lastly, the following issue comment by Jest maintainer Simen helped clarify what was happening in my case: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2524#issuecomment-902027138

Comment: Note that in the specific case where this is caused by indirectly by `isomorphic-fetch` (which in turn needs `whatwg-url`) you can probably get away with just mocking isomorphic-fetch:
```js
jest.mock('isomorphic-fetch', () =>
  () => Promise.resolve({
    json: () => ({}),
  })
);
```

Comment: This saved my bacon today, decided to mark my whole library as a node env `testEnvironment: 'node',`.

Comment: This doesn't work if you need to say access the 'window' object in your test file.

Comment: @scottseeker I believe you need to mock the `window` object for that. Here's a question/answer combo with solutions for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885841/how-can-i-mock-the-javascript-window-object-using-jest

Answer (score 3):

To add to [@leonheess's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68468204/14681457) in TypeScript:

Add to the top of your testfile (in which the error occurs, before the line that causes the error):

```js
import { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } from 'util'
global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder
// @ts-expect-error
global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder
```

Even when trying nicely, e.g.

```
import { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } from 'util'
global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder
global.TextDecoder = { prototype: TextDecoder }
```

I got errors like

```
Type 'typeof TextDecoder' is missing the following properties from type 'TextDecoder': decode, encoding, fatal, ignoreBOMts(2739)
```

Or with

```
global.TextDecoder = {prototype: new TextDecoder("utf-8")}
```

I get

```
Type 'import("util").TextDecoder' is not assignable to type 'TextDecoder'.
  Types of property 'decode' are incompatible.
    Type '(input?: ArrayBuffer | ArrayBufferView | null | undefined, options?: { stream?: boolean | undefined; } | undefined) => string' is not assignable to type '(input?: BufferSource | undefined, options?: TextDecodeOptions | undefined) => string'.
      Types of parameters 'input' and 'input' are incompatible.
        Type 'BufferSource | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ArrayBuffer | ArrayBufferView | null | undefined'.
          Type 'ArrayBufferView' is not assignable to type 'ArrayBuffer | ArrayBufferView | null | undefined'.
            Type 'ArrayBufferView' is missing the following properties from type 'DataView': getFloat32, getFloat64, getInt8, getInt16, and 17 more.
```

So better to just assign and ignore the incompatibilities.

```
import { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } from 'util'
global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder
// @ts-expect-error
global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder
```

**EDIT:** I know this is ugly, but found no other way.

Answer (score -8):

Make sure your `whatwg-url` package has version `^10.0.0` at least