# Testing NextJS and Jest ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined

Tags: next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am getting this error message while trying to learn how to test next.js applications
I have tried import the Text Encoder from utils at the top of the config as well as test file with no success

```
  ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined



  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/encoding.js:2:21)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/url-state-machine.js:5:34)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/URL-impl.js:2:13)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/URL.js:442:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/whatwg-url/webidl2js-wrapper.js:3:13)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/whatwg-url/index.js:3:34)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/src/index.ts:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb/src/connection_string.ts:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb/src/mongo_client.ts:11:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb/src/change_stream.ts:17:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb/src/index.ts:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/binary.js:8:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/index.js:7:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:7:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongoose/index.js:8:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (library/mongoDB.js:15:56)
  at Object.<anonymous> (library/players.js:15:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (pages/index.js:18:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (tests/index.test.js:6:53)
```

Jest Config File

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest')
    const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: './',
})
const customJestConfig = {
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
}
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig)
```

Package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "eslint": "8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.3.0",
    "jest": "^29.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.1.1"
  }
```

index.test.js

```
import Home from '../pages/index'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'

describe('Home Page', () => {
  it('renders home component',
    () => {
      render(<Home />)
      expect(screen.getByTestId('home-page')).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
})
```

Comment: Do any of these answer your question: [Why am I getting "TextEncoder is not defined" in Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68468203/why-am-i-getting-textencoder-is-not-defined-in-jest) or [ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697858/referenceerror-textencoder-is-not-defined)?

Answer (score 5):

I would do it by mocking `TextEncoder` on a dedicated file which will be placed as a setup file on jest config.

This way I think you should get rid of that error.

```js
// text-encoder.mock.ts
import { TextEncoder } from 'util';

global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;


// jest.config.ts
const nextJest = require('next/jest');
const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: './',
});
const customJestConfig = {
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  setupFiles: [
    '<rootDir>/path/to/text-encoder.mock.ts',
  ],
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig)
```

Comment: The same error still occurs, I dont understand I have tried everything .

Comment: Works for me, thanks. I had to add TextDecoder along with TextEncoder.

Comment: Worked for me when I added it to `jest.setup.js`.  Thanks :)