# TextDecoder is not defined when testing react component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, referenceerror

I have created a project that is using firebase for authentication and real-time database and i have created a simple test case for the component that the top option of the select element should be 'us' and 'technology' but it is giving me "TEXTDECODER IS NOT DEFINED" in firebase configuration file from where i am using all the database and authentication functions like getAuth() and ref() etc.

```
src/components/News.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: TextDecoder is not defined

      1 | import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
      2 | import { getDatabase, ref, set, } from "firebase/database";
    > 3 | import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
        |
```

How to solve this ?

```
import React from 'react';
import { render,} from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import News from './News';

test('renders with default option "Technology"', async () => {
  const { getByLabelText } = render(<News />);

  const countrySelect = getByLabelText('Country:');
  const categorySelect = getByLabelText('Category:');


  expect(countrySelect).toHaveValue('us'); // Assuming 'us' is the default country
  expect(categorySelect).toHaveValue('technology'); // Assuming 'technology' is the default category
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68468203/why-am-i-getting-textencoder-is-not-defined-in-jest?

Comment: I have tried that but not working.
somehow the error is gone but now i am getting the error like :
"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"
this error is occuring when i am writing test case for this file before writing test case it was not an error.
Now how to deal with it?