# Jest SpyOn returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to write a jest unit test using react-testing-library and jest without the use of enzyme as from research that I've done it appears that [enzyme will not be supported by react 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72029189/does-enzyme-support-react-version-18). Therefore I'm pre-emptively attempting to write my tests using only the above.

The documentation and [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769404/jest-spyon-function-called) I've found suggest that the spyOn method can be passed the Component.prototype (in this case EmailForm.prototype) and then the specific method name on which you are attempting to spy (in this case handleAddEmail). This method is defined as a regular method on my EmailForm component.

The linked question does mention specifically the render should follow the spy so that the spy object is then initialised which is what I've attempted to implement in my test below yet it still comes back with `Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given`

My test is below:

```
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import EmailForm from "./EmailForm";

const mockSubmit = jest.fn();

const renderComponent = () => {
    return render(<EmailForm actionType="send_email" actionOrigin="Communications" handleActionFormSubmit={mockSubmit} />);
};


describe("EmailForm component", () => {

    it("handles add email with Enter key press", async () => {
        const handleAddEmailSpy = jest.spyOn(EmailForm.prototype, "handleAddEmail");
        renderComponent();
        const recipientField = screen.getByTestId("recipient-field");

        fireEvent.change(recipientField, { target: { value: "f@gmail.com" } });
        fireEvent.keyDown(recipientField, { key: "Enter" });

        expect(handleAddEmailSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

The method attached to an MUI textfield being spied on is as follows:

```
// Function to handle adding new email recipient
  const handleAddEmail = (newEmail: string) => {
    if (!newEmail.trim()) {
      formik.setFieldError("recipient", 
      t("FormValidation.Recipient_Required"));
      return;
    }

    if (!formik.values.recipients.includes(newEmail)) {
      // Add new email recipient
      formik.setFieldValue("recipients", [
        ...formik.values.recipients,
        newEmail
      ]);
      formik.setFieldValue("recipient", "");
    }
  };
```

I've linked [a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/email-form-fjysy4?file=/EmailForm.test.tsx) for my current form and test. I'd appreciate any assistance with this as I'm unsure why the spy is seemingly undefined.

Comment: Please put a [mre] _in the question_ - off-site links like CodeSandbox are strictly complementary.

Comment: Spying on the prototype would work if you wanted to observe the interaction with a method on a class-based component, but **not** for a locally-defined function inside a function-based component. It's also bad practice. Test _behaviour_, not implementation - what should the user see as a result?