Jest-environment-jsdom not working with MSW
I have a custom Webpack setup with type: module and TS. Everything works fine until I try to run tests having Mock Service Worker "integrated".
I have this folder structure
├── mocks/
│   ├── handlers.ts
│   └── server.ts
├── node_modules/
├── public/
├── src/
├── webpack/
├── .babelrc
├── .gitignore
├── jest.config.json
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.test.json
├── README.md
└── setupTests.ts

/jest.config.json
{
  "preset": "ts-jest",
  "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom",
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./setupTests.ts"],
  "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "<rootDir>"],
  "testEnvironmentOptions": {
    "customExportConditions": [""]
  },
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
  }
}

/setupTests.ts
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { server } from './mocks/server';

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());

/mocks/server.ts
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';
import { handlers } from './handlers';

// Configuracion para poder usar el server en los test
export const server = setupServer(...handlers);

I got the simplest test
describe('Simple Test', () => {
  it('should be true', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});

If I remove "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom", it works but if I leave that line it never gets there.
I must use Jest but I cannot seem to get it to work with MSW. Keep getting this error:
   ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined

    > 1 | import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';


https://mswjs.io/docs/faq/#requestresponsetextencoder-is-not-defined-jest

Does this answer your question? ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined during test running with jest and msw v2.0

Or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/68468203/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/57712235/3001761

Not really, cause my problem included having the ESM

@jonrsharpe I saw that from MSW, but when I tried it because I am using ESM it was a complete mess, so that's why my answer fixes the problem for those using ESM

I found the solution by extending JSDOM thanks to joel-daros over here.
I had to do a few changes to make it work with ESM but it now makes Jest and MSW work together
json-extended.js
// Jest environment extended with Web APIs para tranbajar con MSW
import { TestEnvironment } from 'jest-environment-jsdom';
import { EnvironmentContext, JestEnvironmentConfig } from '@jest/environment';

class JSDOMEnvironmentExtended extends TestEnvironment {
  constructor(config: JestEnvironmentConfig, context: EnvironmentContext) {
    super(config, context);

    this.global.ReadableStream = ReadableStream;
    this.global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;
    this.global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;

    this.global.Blob = Blob;
    this.global.File = File;
    this.global.Headers = Headers;
    this.global.FormData = FormData;
    this.global.Request = Request;
    this.global.Response = Response;
    this.global.fetch = fetch;
    this.global.structuredClone = structuredClone;
  }
}

export default JSDOMEnvironmentExtended;

And then editing jest.config.json
...
"testEnvironment": "<rootDir>/jsdom-extended.ts",
...

